# need preg_match_all links

Tags: php, regex

i have a string like this one:

```
$string = "some text
  http://dvz.local/index/index/regionId/28
        http://stuff.kiev.ua/roadmap_page.php http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php
         http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php#qwe";
```

need to get all links.

i tried this way: `/http:\/\/(.*)[|\s]?/`

returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(42) "http://dvz.local/index/index/regionId/28\r\n"
    [1] =>
    string(77) "http://stuff.kiev.ua/roadmap_page.php http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php\r\n"
    [2] =>
    string(41) "http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php#qwe"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(34) "dvz.local/index/index/regionId/28\r"
    [1] =>
    string(69) "stuff.kiev.ua/roadmap_page.php http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php\r"
    [2] =>
    string(34) "192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php#qwe"
  }
}
```

EDIT 1:
expect:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(42) "http://dvz.local/index/index/regionId/28"
    [1] =>
    string(77) "http://stuff.kiev.ua/roadmap_page.php"
    [2] =>
    string(77) "http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php"
    [3] =>
    string(41) "http://192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php#qwe"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(34) "dvz.local/index/index/regionId/28"
    [1] =>
    string(69) "stuff.kiev.ua/roadmap_page.php"
    [2] =>
    string(69) "192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php"
    [3] =>
    string(34) "192.168.3.192/roadmap_page.php#qwe"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/http:\/\/([^\s]+)/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('|http://([^\s]*)|', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Numerous pages have only relative links to the main document, (thus no http(s):// ... to parse), for those the following works fine, splitting by the `href` attribute:

```
preg_match_all('|href="([^\s]*)"><\/a>|', $html, $output_array);
```

Or even simpler:

```
preg_match_all('|href="(.*?)"><\/a>|', $html, $output_array);
```

Example output:

```
 [0]=>
    string(56) "/broadcast/bla/xZr300"
    [1]=>
    string(50) "/broadcast/lol/fMoott"
```

Answer (score 0):

All links from text

http[s]?[^\s]*

Comment: $text = preg_replace('/(http[s]?[^\s]*)/','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$text);