# finding URLs within a string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a strings that contain URLs, and I want to be able to select the whole string. By which I mean break up into an array, and replace with a different URL.
I am just struggling to get  my head around how to get the full URL, which is done presumably for searching for strpos of http, and then the strpos of the next white space, the next white space, but I cant seem to get my head around how to achieve this.

```
$test = 'testing the test http://www.effef.com this is the end';
echo $pos = strpos($test,'http');
```

In this string, we would want to get the string 'http://www.effef.com'

How can you create a variable of a string which is a URL from a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116215/need-preg-match-all-links)

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample data

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to break up that in an array and loop through it to replace it. You can just use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for your purpose.

```
$string = 'testing the test http://www.effef.com this is the end http://www.effef.com';

$replacement = 'http://www.newurl.com';
$regex = '/http:\/\/([^\s]+)/';

// if you are always sure that the url you want to replace is same then
// $regex = '/http\:\/\/www\.effef\.com/';

$new_string = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $string);

var_dump($new_string);
```

Here is the working **[php-fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ces8-4736)**

However if you want to get that in an array for whatever reason, you can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$test = 'testing the test http://www.effef.com this is the end http://www.facebook.com';
$arr = explode(" ", $test);
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     if (strpos($value, 'http') !== false) { echo $value."<br />"; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$string = "testing the test https://www.effef.com this is the end";

if (preg_match('/https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+/', $string, $find_url)) {

$url = $find_url[0];

echo $url;

}
```

For me it echos out url http://www.effef.com/