# How to find video link,image link or simple website link from paragraph in PHP

Tags: php, regex, html, php-5.6

I have a paragraph which has contain video links,image links and URL. The problem is, I am unable to find links from paragraph, i'm pretty new in YII2 and PHP and i dont find how to broken paragraph. Here is my paragraph

```
sed do eiusmod tempor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KAhuyyt incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 http://example.com/ Ut enim ad minim veniam,http://test.au/ quis nostrud https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KAhyt 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.example.jpg 
Duis aute irure dolor123.jpeg,example.png in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
 esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
 non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Does your paragraph contains html content?

Comment: no  i'm used simple paragraph in html body

Comment: As per my understanding you need to parse link form html. You can use this library to do that http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116215/need-preg-match-all-links